# Spring Boot deploy to Heroku: unable to access jarfile target/springApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I have a spring boot app deploying to heroku

Procfile
`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

pom `<artifactId>springApp</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <packaging>war</packaging>`

when i deploy i can access my apps pages but i get an error when i run heroku logs

`Error: unable to access jarfile target/springApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

From what i can tell, when i deploy the application heroku uses `java -Dserver.port=26325 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/bigfans-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to run the process. It does not use the commands specified in the Procfile.

I have tried to find what the cause could be but I have not found anything online.

Comment: Did you commit your Procfile? Are you on the correct branch? If you created/edited your Procfile on a branch but deployed with `git push heroku master`, the changes in your branch will not be deployed.

Comment: I committed the Procfile onto master and pushed the code to github. I am using heroku's github deployment method.

Comment: The dynos that i have configured are visible on my heroku dashboard but my logs indicate that they are not being used when deploying.